# Adding a random class to element from an array that duplicates using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I'm creating a matching game and I'm trying to add a class from an array to match against.
The code I have below creates the classes I need, then randomizes them.

My problem is in the randomizeDeck function. I'm trying to add each of the classes to the specified element twice. When I console.log the code the classes gets added to the first six elements but not the last six, which I need it to do so that I have the classes to match against in the matching game I'm creating.

```
var cardDeck = new Array();

function createDeck() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        cardDeck.push("card-" + i);
    }
}
createDeck();

var randDeck = cardDeck.sort(randOrd);

function randomizeDeck() {
    card.each(function(i){
        $(this).addClass(randDeck[i]);
    });
}
randomizeDeck();
```

Comment: what is card in "card.each"? what this variable have?

Comment: The variable card is a div with the class card. That div is replicated 12 times.

Comment: andi's solution is probably your best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a separate variable to keep track of the index, rather that the `each` index. Once you've gone through the pack once, it might be a good idea to shuffle the deck again so the order is different on the second pass. YMMV.

```
function sortCards(randOrd) {
  randDeck = cardDeck.sort(randOrd);
}

function randomizeDeck() {
  var count = 0;
  cards.each(function(i) {
    if (i === 6) { count = 0; sortCards(randOrd); }
    $(this).addClass(randDeck[count]);
    count++;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your createDeck function needs to create 12 classes instead of 6.  Just push each one twice:

```
function createDeck() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        cardDeck.push("card-" + i);
        cardDeck.push("card-" + i);
    }
}
```

Then you'll have an array of 12 classes (2 each of 6 unique classes), which will be randomized and assigned to the 12 cards.

Comment: Don't forget the randomized sort that happens on her initial array.

Comment: @BumbleB2na - That sort will work fine with this.  Do you see an issue?

Comment: actually no.. now that you mention it that would mix them up better than in my solution

Answer (score 0):

Your randomizeDeck() function can be rewritten to use the same array of class names twice:

```
function randomizeDeck() {
    card.each(function(i){
        if(i < 6)
            $(this).addClass(randDeck[i])
        else
            $(this).addClass(randDeck[i-6]);
    });
}
```

Note: I would rewrite the variable `card` as `$cards` so that you know it's a jQuery object and in this case a collection of them. Otherwise, its hard to tell it apart from any other javascript var.

Comment: That is correct, there are a dozen cards that I'm trying to add a class that is duplicated for matching purposes. e.g. card-1 that has a match of card-1 etc.

Comment: Then you're going outside the bounds of your array

Comment: Any suggestion on how I could apply the same array to the entire block of elements?

Comment: Sure but I'm still only guessing with my answer. Some of your code is hidden, such as assigning the value of `card` and seeing more of your code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - it's tested now updated
SEE THIS FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/8XBM2/1/

```
var cardDeck = new Array();

function createDeck() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        cardDeck.push("card-" + i);
    }
}
createDeck();
var randDeck = cardDeck.sort();
alert(randDeck);

function randomizeDeck() {
    var x = 0;
    $('div').each(function(i){
     if ( i > 5) { 

                $(this).addClass(randDeck[x]);
         x++; 
      } else {
        $(this).addClass(randDeck[i]);
    }
    });
}
randomizeDeck();
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to restart the iteration again after 6

Comment: Yeah, I want the array to be applied twice so that I have a class that I can match two cards against.