# Select css style from group of styles

Tags: javascript, html, sass, less

I am generating Div for each entry in my database.

```
<div class='db-green'>Sample Code</div>
<div class='db-blue'>Sample Code</div>
<div class='db-blue'>Sample Code</div>
<div class='db-yellow'>Sample Code</div>
```

What I desire is to select the color in Div class by random supose by defining the color's inside an array.

I am hoping for a solution with Less or sass or should i use JS ?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the issue. You need to randomly select a color and associate it to an element?

Comment: Are looking for something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036175/adding-a-random-class-to-element-from-an-array-that-duplicates-using-jquery

Comment: Both Sass and LESS are CSS preprocessors.

Comment: Yes, Something like that. It's more like I have 3 classes defined, db-green, db-blue, db-yellow. And child styling is done relative to those classes. So I want to randomly select any of those 3 classes ? I wanted to see if I can do it with LESS or Sass ?

Comment: Do you really want it to be *random*? Assuming you want to use a "nice" predefined array of colors I would do something like [this](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/tKdAm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript function that generates a random color:

```
function getColor() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    return "#"+ r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16) ;
}
```

And then use JS DOM (or JQuery) to change the CSS `background-color` attribute of each `div`:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs.item(i).style.backgroundColor = getColor();
    divs.item(i).innerHTML = getColor();
}
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/LjK8K/)**

**UPDATE**: You can also call a method like that inside Less using *backticks* to have access to the underlying JavaScript processor (I'm not sure if this will work in the non-JavaScript Less implementations such as less4j, since it's not a documented feature). This mixin:

```
.generateColor() { 
    @color: color(`"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`);
}
```

will set the `@color` variable to a randomly generated color. You can then use it in a selector block:

```
.db-color-1 {
    .generateColor();
    background-color: @color;
}

.db-color-2 {
    .generateColor();
    background-color: @color;
}

.db-color-3 {
    .generateColor();
    background-color: @color;
}
```

And each class will have (hopefully) a different color.

Comment: I did this in PHP instead, I was hoping to do in Sass or Less. But this is the idea. Thank you.

Comment: I thought you wanted to do something in the client side. You can insert JavaScript inside Less using backticks. Calling this mixin: `.generateColor() { @color: color(\`"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)\`);}` inside a selector block, you can get a random color in the `@color` variable: `.db-green {.generateColor(); background-color: @color;}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution to a problem similar to the one you called out: [randomly display a div class using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476614/randomly-display-a-div-class-using-jquery)

You can use jQuery to define color to random `div` elements:

```
var divs = ['.db-green', '.db-blue', '.db-yellow']; // possible divs
var color = ["blue", "yellow", "red"]; // potential colors
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length);
var entry = divs[random];
$(entry).css("color", color[0]);
```